# Why can an object reference be accessed in inner function members but not in inner property members?

Tags: javascript, scope

For example this fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined`:

```
var obj = {
  a: 23,
  b: obj.a,
};
```

while this works:

```
var obj = {
  a: 23,
  getA: function() {
    return obj.a;
  }
};
```

?

**BONUS QUESTION**

So why doesn't this throw a `ReferenceError`:

```
var obj = {
  a: 23,
  b: obj
};
```

after all, `obj` still doesn't exist yet! It would throw a `ReferenceError` if I was trying to access a not-yet-defined thing elsewhere!

Comment: Because your inside an object that hasn't been created yet, and no reference to `obj` exists. The function on the other hand runs later, when the object exists

Comment: @adeneo the function is still being defined while the object doesn't exist yet either. So the javascript engine simply doesn't care what's inside the function body during definiton?

Comment: *"So the javascript engine simply doesn't care what's inside the function body during definiton? "* Pretty much (except is still has to be syntactically valid). Here is a simpler example: `function foo() { alert(i); }`. It's perfectly OK to define the function, it doesn't throw an error. Only when you **call** the function, it will try to read `i` at which point it throws a reference error.

Comment: Thanks all, I see.. Never seen that in Java (JavaScript's big brother. jk)

Comment: JavaScript and Java are *entirely* different languages. You shouldn't compare anything about them. Doing so will bring confusion (like the one that brought about this question!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access members of an object on an object that hasn't yet been constructed.

In the second example, the function `getA` would be called **after** the object `obj` has been created, thus it's accessible.

Comment: So the function body is simply a string to the javascript engine during definition? And that string only gets evaluated once it is run??

Comment: The function body is just a function body. Everything inside the function is evaluated when the function is called. It's not a string, it's just the way functions work.

Comment: Try this: `x = function() { console.log(doesntexist) }`. You can declare the function and make the assignment OK. The error occurs when you call `x()` and it tries to find the value of `doesntexist`. If you then set `window.doesntexist = 1`, then `x()`  will run successfully.

Answer (score 2):

What you have in the second example is a *closure*. A variable reference inside a function (a.k.a. a closure) refers to the variable itself, not the value of the variable at the time that the function is defined.

Observe:

```js
var a;

function loga() {
  console.log(a);
}

loga(); // undefined

a = 3;

loga(); // 3

a = "hello";

loga(); // hello
```

What's happening in your example is exactly the same. You execute the function *after* `obj` already has a value, so everything works.

As Felix Kling points out, it doesn't matter where your variable is declared, as long as it is declared *somewhere* within the scope. This is known colloquially as "variable hoisting".

You could even do this if you really wanted to:

```js
function loga() {
  console.log(a);
}

var a = 3;

loga(); // 3
```

Comment: At least that's how it is in JS.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, JS is the language we are talking about.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. A closure is usually defined as preserving its reference context. In my example the reference context doesn't even contain the `obj` reference -- it does not exist yet!

Comment: @user511287: It does exist. See my answer.

Comment: @user511287 I'm not sure what you mean by "preserving its reference context", but what I said is right. `obj` exists everywhere inside the function that contains it (see also: variable hoisting).

Comment: @FelixKling but only **after** obj has been created, which is **after** the closure is being defined. And closures preserve the reference context that existed during the closure definition, no?

Comment: @user511287: You are confusing the existing of the **variable** with the existence of the **value**.

Comment: @user511287 What is a "reference context"?

Comment: Thanks Felix, I see. @JLRishe the set of all existing references (variables) reachable from within the function but defined outside the function

Answer (score 1):

> So why doesn't this throw a ReferenceError:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>   a: 23,
>   b: obj
> };
> ```
>
> after all, obj still doesn't exist yet! It would throw a ReferenceError if I was trying to access a not-yet-defined thing elsewhere!

The **variable** `obj` exists because of **hoisting**. It just doesn't have a **value** yet. Your example is equivalent to

```
var obj; // declaration is hoisted to the top of the scope
obj = {
  a: 23,
  b: obj
};
```

`obj` exists but has the (default) value `undefined`.

Comment: oh i see (dummy text)

Comment: Think about a variable as a container. The container exists but you haven't put anything in it yet. That's why `var obj = { a: 23, b: obj.a, };` fails. You are trying to get something out of the container before you put something in. However, you can still take (reference) the container itself (`obj`) because it exists independently of its content.

Comment: @user511287 That's why you should ask separate questions as separate questions instead of asking "bonus question"s after the fact. :)